# Using 'Grouped Exposed Filters' for combinations of Taxonomy terms

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a taxonomy of 'Investment Vehicles' containing 3 terms.

[image]

When a user adds a piece of content, they can select 1 or up to all 3 investment vehicles terms to classify their content.

[image]

I am then applying an 'Exposed Group Filter' as a radio input so that the user can filter between content with different combinations of 'Investment Vehicles.'

[image]

In the screenshot below you can see that the default 'any' option returns my 2 pieces of content but any change does not return any content at all and I am receiving the following error:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also...If I change these to checkboxes they work perfectly and exactly how I want them to.  But I don't want the user to be able to make multiple selections here.